# jquery causing “white” on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've searched this a bit on the forum, and can't seem to figure out how to fix the common issue of white flashing when a new page loads.

I've tried Chris Coyer's example of placing this above my other javascript:

```
    // Prevent variables from being global
(function () {

      /*
          1. Inject CSS which makes iframe invisible
      */

    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        ref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0] ||
              document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

    div.innerHTML = '&shy;<style> iframe { visibility: hidden; } </style>';

    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ref);

    /*
        2. When window loads, remove that CSS,
           making iframe visible again
    */

    window.onload = function() {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }

})();
```

but, still flashing.  I'm a noob to javascript, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

The page that is the worst is: http://thegoodgirlsnyc.com/test/new/index3_7.php

Comment: you have control over the source of the site.  Just set the iframe or whatnot to display:none and then `window.onload = function() {
        $("#myiframe").show();
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Jquery try wrapping your function with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 /* Code goes here */
});
```

This will execute your code when the document is ready (fully loaded)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're executing tasks throughout the pageload. You're getting the flashing because code is being run in-time with page load.

You need to abstract the running of the code behind a unified point. This is where things like `$(document).ready()` are nice from jQuery. It happens upon DOM completion, but before `window` load completion. This means it happens before visual, which prevents screen flash Javascriptiong.

It seems like you're worried about the global namespace:

```
jQuery( function($){
    $('iframe').hide();

    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('iframe').show();
    });
});
```

This is an easy solution that alleviates the namespacing issue, and you won't have to refactor current code. So my answer is two parts:

1. Use jQuery.
2. Use namespacing.

If you still get screen flashing using the above, you need to set the `display` to `none` in the stylesheet for the `iframe` element.